# Javascript sort list works only onve

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sorting, html-lists

I'm trying to implement a question like system.
The questions should reorder with every like based on the data attribute 'vote'.
So every time a like event is received from the sockets the sort function gets called.
The first time a question gets liked everything works fine and the list is sorted.
But then it stops sorting. I already checked the data values.

Here is my js function:

```
function sortQuestionList() {
  $('#questionList li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('#questionList');
        
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('vote')) < ($(a).data('vote')) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got a working solution with dataset instead of data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort_li` function doesn't return the values `sort` expects. It should return:

- A negative number if `a` comes before `b`
- A positive number if `b` comes before `a`
- **Zero if they're the same**

Your code isn't doing that last thing. This makes `sort` unable to do its job correctly.

Instead:

```
function sortQuestionList() {
    $("#questionList li").sort(sort_li).appendTo("#questionList");
          
    function sort_li(a, b) {
        return $(a).data("vote") - $(b).data("vote");  // ***
    }
}
```

*(That assumes that the value of `vote` is numeric.)*

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!! I tried your solution but it's not working after the first sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function works. However, it is not stable. You should write

```js
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return $(b).data("vote") - $(a).data("vote");
  }
```

Anyways, this is not your problem.
I made an example here and its working just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/sort-questions-stackoverlow-49hvi?file=/src/index.js

The code you provided is not the root of your problem.
We cannot provide any further help without a non working example. Please make a minimal pen or codesandbox.

All I can say is: Make sure you call the sort function everytime you update the list items. Make sure no other function overwrites those changes. Make sure you use the right properties ('data-votes' instead of 'votes').

Comment: Works fine with dataset instead of data. Thanks!!